# Facebook Posts Not Posting From App Unless Dialog Box Written In

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit

I use ShareKit to share stories from my app to Facebook and Twitter.  I click everything in the app to share, and it pops up with the dialog box giving me the option to Share or Cancel.  If I click Share, it never posts.  Not in my timeline or news feed, nor where anyone else can see it.  If I type something in the dialog box first, it will share.  Is this a bug with ShareKit or with Facebook, and how can I remedy this issue?

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:[NSURL URLWithString:_entry.articleUrl] title:_entry.articleTitle];
        [item setCustomValue:@"http://www.316apps.com/icon.png" forKey:@"picture"];
        [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Comment: and the error message, and whether or not the post appears in activity log

Comment: No error message, it shows it posts fine, but doesn't show up in Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem might be, that you use obsolete [original shareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com). Facebook has deprecated "message" parameter in FBDialog, which is used when you share text. A workaround is to use Facebook's Graph api. This is addressed in [ShareKit 2](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/). If you decide to try it, make sure to follow [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) literally, as many things have changed.

Comment: I am not using ShareKit to share text at all.  See above edit for what I am using

Comment: SHKFacebook and SHKItem are parts of shareKit. So it seems that you do use shareKit. I second my answer :)

Comment: I NEVER SAID I DON'T USE SHAREKIT, IT IS IN THE FIRST LINE OF MY QUESTION!  I said I don't use ShareKit to share TEXT!  If you look at the code in my answer, I am not using ShareKit for sharing text, but for sharing URL, which does not use Facebook's deprecated message at all.